# Generic CQRS Query handler with custom return type

Tags: c#, .net, generics, mediator

I am trying to build a generic query handler using the [MediatR](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR) (v8) library. Let's jump to the code:
First of all I have an abstract query class like this:

```
public abstract class Query<TQueryResult> : IRequest<TQueryResult>
{
    public Guid Id { get; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    public DateTime Timestamp { get; }

    protected Query()
    {
        Timestamp = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

From the corresponding query handler I would like to return a `Result` wrapper object, which looks as the following:

```
public class Result<T> 
{
    public T Payload { get;  }
    public string FailureReason { get;  }

    public bool IsSuccess => FailureReason == null;

    public Result(T payload)
    {
        Payload = payload;
    }

    public Result(string failureReason)
    {
        FailureReason = failureReason;
    }

    public static Result<T> Success(T payload)
        => new Result<T>(payload);

    public static Result<T> Failure(string reason)
        => new Result<T>(reason);

    public static implicit operator bool(Result<T> result) => result.IsSuccess;

}
```

And last but not least, lets see the query handler:

```
public abstract class AbstractQueryHandler<TQuery, TQueryResult, TResultValue> : IRequestHandler<TQuery, TQueryResult>
    where TQuery : Query<TQueryResult>
    where TQueryResult : class
{

    public Task<TQueryResult> Handle(TQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            return HandleQuery(request);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(Result<TResultValue>.Failure(GetFailureMessage(e)) as TQueryResult);
        }
    }

    public abstract Task<TQueryResult> HandleQuery(TQuery request);

    private static string GetFailureMessage(Exception e)
    {
        return "There was an error while executing query: \r\n" + e.Message;
    }
}
```

To be honest I am not pleased with this solution due to the three type parameters I have in the query handler. It might be possible to extract one from another using reflection but I think that is not the proper and right approach for this. I introduced `TResultValue` in order to make the catch part of the code working so use it as a generic type in my created error `Result` wrapper object. Let's see some corresponding tests to reveal my concerns regarding. First lets see the Query and the query handler in the production code:

```
public class GetAllProductsQuery : Query<Result<IEnumerable<ProductDto>>>
{
}


public class GetAllProductsQueryHandler : AbstractQueryHandler<GetAllProductsQuery, Result<IEnumerable<ProductDto>>, IEnumerable<ProductDto>>
{
    private readonly IProductEntityDao _productEntityDao;

    public GetAllProductsQueryHandler(IProductEntityDao productEntityDao)
    {
        _productEntityDao = productEntityDao;
    }

    public override async Task<Result<IEnumerable<ProductDto>>> HandleQuery(GetAllProductsQuery request)
    {
        var products = await _productEntityDao.GetAllAsync();

        return Result<IEnumerable<ProductDto>>.Success(products);
    }
}
```

And then the test:

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task GivenSingleProduct_thenGetAllProductsQuerySend_thenReturnsSingleProduct()
    {
        await AddToDbContextAsync(ProductFakes.ProductWithAllPropsFilled1);

        var result = await SendAsync(new GetAllProductsQuery());

        Check.That(result.IsSuccess).IsTrue();
        Check.That(result.Payload).CountIs(1);
    }
```

where `SendAsync<T>` looks as the following:

```
public Task<TResponse> SendAsync<TResponse>(IRequest<TResponse> request)
{
    var mediator = Provider.GetService<IMediator>();
    return mediator.Send(request);
}
```

As you can see in the `GetAllProductsQueryHandler` there is some kind of duplication when declaring the three types, namely `<GetAllProductsQuery, Result<IEnumerable<ProductDto>>, IEnumerable<ProductDto>>`. It seems really fishy to me. I also tried many other possibilities, checking articles and SO questions/answers on the internet but could not come up with a cleaner solution. I also tried using dynamic object instead of generic but I would like to have the strong type check in compiler time. 
So my question is: Is it possible to reduce the number of type parameters of `AbstractQueryHandler`handler to 2, resulting in a cleaner solution? Do you see any other code improvement? Thanks in advance for you help!